# How to get selected items in OpenSymphony WebWork select

Tags: java, jsp, webwork

I inherited somebody else's code, and it uses OpenSymphony WebWorks, which I've never encountered before.  I'm trying to "cargo cult" a small fix to it.  It includes the following in a JSP:

```
      <ww:select
    name="'selectedOrigDoctypes'"
    value="selectedOrigDoctypes"
    size="5"
    multiple="true"
    cssClass="'doctype'"
    list="origDoctypeChoices"
    theme="'simple'" />
```

and I can't figure out how to get the selected items out of the list.  The list is correctly populated with the contents of the Action bean's origDoctypeChoices property.  I thought I'd just have to implement a "setSelectedOrigDoctypes(List docTypes)" in the Action bean, but that's not working.  Instead I see the following in the log files:

```
150876 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork.interceptor.ParametersIntercep
tor  - Setting params {selectedOrigDoctypes=[Ljava.lang.String;@5249c469}
150965 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork.util.CompoundRootAccessor  - No object in the CompoundRoot has a property named 'selectedOrigDoctypes'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what the "selectedOrigDoctypes=[Ljava.lang.String;" thing meant - I changed "origDoctypeChoices" from a List to an String[], and everything worked.